# When should I split some task into asynchronous tinier tasks?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm writing a personal project in Node and I'm trying to figure out when a task should be asynchronously splitted. Let's say I have this "4-Step-Task", they are not very expensive (the most expensive its the one who iterates over an array of objects and trying to match a URL with a RegExp, and the array probably won't have more than 20 or 30 objects).

```
part1().then(y => {
  doTheSecondPart
}).then(z => {
  doTheThirdPart
}).then(c => {
  doTheFourthPart
});
```

The other way will be just executing one after another, but nothing else will progress until this task is done. With the above approach, others tasks can progress at least a little bit between each part.

Is there any criteria about when this approach should be prefered over a classic synchronous one?

Sorry my bad english, not my native language.

Comment: You have a basic misunderstanding of how this works. Splitting up "expensive" processes in the `then` code doesn't allow you to run in more than one thread. You still have a single execution thread.

Comment: The purpose of ```.then``` is to make asynchronous execution behave synchronously, not the other way around.

Comment: @Tarazed - `.then()` does not make asynchronous execution behave synchronously.  It helps you manage asynchronous operations, but it doesn't make it behave synchronously in any way.

Answer (score 1):

All you've described is synchronous code that isn't very long to run.  First off, there's no reason to even use promises for that type of code.  Secondly, there's no reason to break it up into chunks.  All you would be doing with either of those choices is making the code more complicated to write, more complicated to test and more complicated to understand and it would also run slower.  All of those are undesirable.

If you force even synchronous code into a promise, then a `.then()` handler will give some other code a chance to run between `.then()` handlers, but only certain types of events can be run there because processing a resolved promise is one of the highest priority things to do in the event queue system.  It won't, for example, allow another incoming http request arriving on your server to start to run.

If you truly wanted to allow other requests to run and so on, you would be better off just putting the code (without promises) into a WorkerThread and letting it run there and then communicate back the result via messaging.  If you wanted to keep it in the main thread, but let any other code run, you'd probably have to use a short `setTimeout()` delay to truly let all possible other types of tasks run in between.

So, if this code doesn't take much time to run, there's just really no reason to mess with complicating it.  Just let it run in the fastest, quickest and simplest way.

If you want more concrete advice, then please show some actual code and provide some timing information about how long it takes to run.  Iterating through an array of 20-30 objects is nothing in the general scheme of things and is not a reason to rewrite it into timesliced pieces.

As for code that iterates over an array/list of items doing matching against some string, this is exactly what the Express web server framework does on every incoming URL to find the matching routes.  That is not a slow thing to do in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous programming is a better fit for code that must respond to events – for example, any kind of graphical UI. An example of a situation where programmers use async but shouldn't is any code that can focus entirely on data processing and can accept a “stop-the-world” block while waiting for data to download.

I use it extensivly with a rest API server as we have no idea of how long a request can take to for a server to respond . So in order for us not to "block the app" while waiting for the server response async requests are most useful

```
part1().then(y => {
doTheSecondPart
 }).then(z => {
 doTheThirdPart
 }).then(c => {
 doTheFourthPart
 });
```

As you have described in your sample is much more of a synchronous procedural process that would not necessarily allow your interface to still work while your algorithm is busy with a process
In the case of a server call, if you still waiting for server to respond the algorithm using **then** is still using up resources and wont free your app up to run any other user interface events, while its waiting for the process to reach the next **then** statement .

You should use Async Await in this instance where you waiting for a user event or a server to respond but do not want your app to hang while waiting for server data...

```js
async function wait() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,2000));
   console.log("awaiting for server once !!")
  return 10;
}

async function wait2() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,3000));
   console.log("awaiting for server twice !!")
  return 10;
}

async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  




 let result = await promise;//.then(async function(){
     console.log(result)
  let promise6 = await wait();
  let promise7 = await wait2();
   
//}); // wait until the promise resolves (*)

  //console.log(result); // "done!"
}

f();
```

This sample should help you gain a basic understanding of how async/ Await works and here are a few resources to research it 
[Promises and Async](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee)
[Mozilla Refrences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)